# MP3 Tags Not Saving in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp3

I'm trying to save MP3 Tags to files in a folder. I have assigned new values from the spreadsheet to the `temp_track` as below but could not find a way to finish the last step to save the files with the new data.

My code:

```
tlt = sheet2.cell(row=a+1, column=14)
            temp_track.title = tlt.value
            print('Title of Song: ' + temp_track.title)
```

Data that shows in the run window:

```
Title of Song: (66 REV 022) - Revelation 22
```

I have tried `TinyTag.tag.save()` but got the error message

```
AttributeError: type object 'TinyTag' has no attribute 'tag'
```

What attribute can be used to save the new MP3 Tags to the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using TinyTag from pypi https://pypi.org/project/tinytag/ or https://github.com/devsnd/tinytag that library is for reads only. It can not be used to modify an existing file.

If you want to edit the ID3 tags for an mp3 file, try mp3-tagger https://pypi.org/project/mp3-tagger/ or https://github.com/artcom-net/mp3-tagger

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I have a question is there one that has the same attributes as TinyTag  that has a save feature?. If so what code code be used to reflect those attributes it has?  Thanks